# I cannot run the Twilio Chat in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, twilio, chat, twilio-programmable-chat

I applied the whole code which provides in github. But it cannot run. Here is the error that I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\androloper\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\480925f2f75f630a7088c0ebfe10d2e9\transformed\jetified-httpclient-4.5.13.jar
      - C:\Users\androloper\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b3786329ec55299ebdf51edf5b161599\transformed\jetified-httpcore-4.4.13.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
     for more information
```

This is the code where I copied:
https://github.com/Zingworks-Sachin/twilio_chat_conversation/tree/main/example/lib
I totally added from this website. How can I solve it?